# Do two equal objects have to have the same toString output?

Tags: java, equals, tostring

Do two equal objects have to have the same toString output?

In code, does the following have to hold in general?

```
if(o1.equals(o2))
  return o1.toString().equals(o2.toString()) // always true?
```

I am asking because I have just written a `toString` method for which the above statement does *not* hold. I could not find any hint at the documentation, but I want to get sure my `toString` method does not break any contract rules.

Comment: Not necessarly, if you printing property not used by equals method. How `toString ()`  defined and what property used by equals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they do not have to have the same `toString()` output in order to be equal. There is no contract in Java that states the `equals()` method must be true for both the object itself and its `toString()` method.

The only contract `equals()` has with other methods is with `hashCode()`:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method [equals] is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

The contract it has irrespective of other methods is:

> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-

Edit: Some people are saying Effective Java by Joshua Bloch says the `toString()` method should use the same fields as the `equals()` method. This is not true. He states:

> While it isn’t as important as obeying the equals and hashCode contracts (Item 8, Item 9), providing a good toString implementation makes your class much more pleasant to use.

What he classifies as a "good implementation" is:

> When practical, the toString method should return all of the interesting information contained in the object, as in the phone number example just shown. It is impractical if the object is large or if it contains state that is not conducive to string representation. Under these circumstances, toString should return a summary such as “Manhattan white pages (1487536 listings)” or “Thread[main,5,main]”.

So no, it in no way relates to the `equals()` method.

Comment: Why not reference the official Javadoc at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object) instead?  It has the same explanation under the `equals` method.

Comment: Joshua Bloch points out that `toString` should be consistent with `equals` at least to the point where it involves the same data used in `equals`, but it can show more. If you think about it, if two objects are equal, it only makes sense that `toString` yield the same value.

Comment: You should reference Java 8 documentation, or later. Java 7 hit End of Life a couple of years ago.

Comment: Good points on the sources used. I've updated the answer to use the javadoc source. Regarding toString's relation to equal's, I've looked into it (by rereading the relevant Effective Java section), and provided responses at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for this. There is a dependency between `equals` and `hashCode`: equal objects must return the same hashCode value. `toString` is only used for printing the object.

Answer (score -1):

There is no contract for toString, only for equals and hashCode. And from my point of view it also doesn't make sense.

Imagine o1 and o2 are of class Person{}, then you get only the string of the reference.

Comment: "string of the reference"? What does that mean? And of course you write `toString` to show relevant information, i.e., the information that determines equality, so no, regardless of what it means, you don't "get only the string of the reference" unless you wrote it that way.

Comment: Something like this Person@78308db1 which is the reference on the heap.

Comment: That's a hashcode with some code string attached, not a "reference on the heap", and why would you leave `toString` like that anyway? Of course you write toString to show relevant information, i.e., the information that determines equality. As stated. The idea is to override `toString` when you override `hashCode`, `equals`, and `compareTo`. Override, not leave untouched. When you override it, you keep it consistent. How about reading _Effective Java_? You'll get the details there.

Answer (score -1):

There's no "requirement" that `hashCode` match `equals`, only a best practice that it do so, or your program won't make sense. Same with `toString`. It should be consistent with `equals`, as should `compareTo` if used. See *Effective Java* by Joshua Bloch for the rationale. People who tell you otherwise need to read that book because they're mistaken.

Comment: I've read the book and it doesn't say anything about toString matching equals. See my answer for relative quotations from Effective Java, 2nd Edition.

Comment: "When practical, the toString method should return all of the interesting information contained in the object", which obviously includes the fields used to determine value equality.

Comment: I disagree, I don't think that implies that it "obviously includes the fields used to determine value equality."  
  
Also, what you quoted is immediately followed with: "It is impractical if the object is large or if it contains state that is not conducive to string representation. Under these circumstances, toString should return a summary such as 'Manhattan white pages (1487536 listings)' or 'Thread[main,5,main]'"